# GNOME window decorations missing in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: gnome

I just set up a new Ubuntu 12.10 installation.

The "Unity" desktop seems to work fine, but when I switch to GNOME, all the window decorations are missing, including the borders and the resize buttons.

Has anyone seen this before?  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `metacity --replace` from the command line.

That should restore the window manager. You may not have a window manager (other then Compiz) installed.